# VBA - Prevent users from saving unless checkbox is checked

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, ms-office

I'm using this macro in order to prevent a user from saving the workbook unless they accept the Terms and Conditions, annotated with a checkbox.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    MsgBox "Please accept the terms and conditions"
    Cancel = True

End Sub
```

But this macro prevents a user from saving indefinitely. How can I make it so the user has to check a checkbox in order to save?

Thanks!

Comment: use If CheckBox1.Value = false Then cancel = true

Comment: A shortest way of it: `If CheckBox1.Value = false Then cancel = true` is: `cancel = CheckBox1.Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = Not Worksheets(2).CheckBoxes(1).Value = 1
    If Cancel Then MsgBox "Please accept the terms and conditions"
End Sub
```

where I assumed:

- Worksheets(2) is the worksheet with the relevant checkbox
- relevant Checkbox is the first in the worksheet
  otherwise change accordingly to your actual case

Comment: Perfect! The checkbox was in the first worksheet, so I just changed Worksheets(1).